# implementing leader election algorithm using RMI in java

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, rmi, distributed-system

i have to submit a distributed system project in a week .. 
i should implement the leader election algorithm written in the following paper

http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~woelfel/paper/leaderelection/le.pdf

i have tried an RMI tutorial example and it done successfully

but now the problem is how can i write the requested leader election algorithm using RMI

i don't want to have a difficult or complex project

the simpler implementation is enough

so can someone help and tell me what should i do? how many servers or clients i need to implement the idea of leader election?

and thanks

Comment: What is your specific question? Cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to comment specifically on the election algorithm, since that seems to be the point of your course, and your homework - I'll leave that up to you.

However, I would think that RMI would not be your best solution, as the discovery phase, while possible, could be much more difficult than other methods.

I'd suggest that you take a look IP/Multicast instead of RMI.

See, for example, http://web.nchu.edu.tw/~jlu/cyut/multicast.shtml